# Views Page Display not printing title

Tags: views, theming, 8

**Problem:** The views page title fails to render as I expect in the Monoset theme.

I'm using Drupal 8.1.9, and the [Monoset](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/zetagraph/2423269) sandbox theme. Monoset uses classy as the base theme. I've created a view with a title. The Page Title block is enabled and set to display.

If I place:

```
{{ page['#title'] }}
```

into my page.html.twig I see the title, though this adds the page title to every page, without regards to the Page Title block settings.

The Seven core theme renders the title as I expect. Bartik and Stark do not.

Looking at the classy templates/views/views-view.html.twig file is this comment:

```
title: Title of the view, only used when displaying in the admin preview.
```

I'm guessing that seven is performing correct preprocessing that bartik, stark and monoset are not performing?

My work-around until I disambiguate this issue is to do a twig page override for this views page.

I'm unclear if

- [Discourage $main_content['#title'] in favor of route titles 
  title callbacks](https://www.drupal.org/node/2359901) and
- [Use _title and _title_callback where
  possible](https://www.drupal.org/node/2403359)

are related issues.